# Is there a beginner introduction to writing Eclipse plugins?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have tried and failed to create to find any good tutorials on writting plugins for Eclipse and the closest I have assumed a large degree of knowledge about the internals of Eclipse.

For what it is worth I have the programming skills to write the plugin. I need help with getting it plugged into Eclipse correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could be an interesting site for you:
http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/

It covers setting up your plugin to advanced plugin tutorials.
I personally use it all the time.

Comment: I have accepted your answer since the site actually is for beginners, which is what I asked for. Vogels site goes way over my head at this point.

Answer (score 3):

The best tutorial I've found is [Lars Vogels Plugin tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html). Have a look at his other [other Eclipse tutorials](http://www.vogella.de/eclipse.html) aswell. Alot of good content there.